# Dynamic form fields arent returning any value

Tags: angular

I am using dynamic forms to create my form in angular. I represent my ingredients with a select of available ones, but because you can add multiple, i need to have dynamically generated selects.

My html:

```
 <form [formGroup]="mealForm">
    <input formControlName="mealName" type="text" class="form-control" /><br/>

    <select formControlName="ingredients" class="form-control">
        <option selected value="">Select an ingredient</option>
        <option *ngFor="let ingredient of myfoods" value="{{ ingredient.id }}">{{ ingredient.name }}</option>
    </select><br/>


    <div formArrayName="additionalIngredients" *ngFor ="let ingredient of additionalIngredients.controls; let i=index">
        <select formControlName="i" class="form-control">
            <option selected value="">Select an ingredient</option>
            <option *ngFor="let ingredient of myfoods" value="{{ ingredient.id }}">{{ ingredient.name }}</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <button (click)="addAdditionalIngredients()" type="button">Add ingredient</button>

</form>
```

My TS code:

```
  mealForm: FormGroup;

  get additionalIngredients(){
    return this.mealForm.get('additionalIngredients') as FormArray;
  }

  addAdditionalIngredients(){
    this.additionalIngredients.push(this.fb.control(''));
  }

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder){}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.mealForm = this.fb.group({
      mealName: [''],
      ingredients: [''],
      additionalIngredients: this.fb.array([])
    });

  }
```

The problem im facing is that when i add a dynamic select the options are empty, but after i unfocus the select it will get populated but the value wont be passed. Here is a example json that i get by picking any kind of option:

```
{ "mealName": "new meal", "ingredients": "1", "additionalIngredients": [ "", "" ] }
```

as you can see "additionlINgredients" which are dynamic selects are empty but my static one "ingredients" has the value of 1 in this case- Expected values are numeric values or id's of the ingredients...

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ftf7ks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace `formControlName="i"` with `[formControlName]="i"` because in first case you assign string value 'i' to formControlName not the value of i:

```
<div formArrayName="additionalIngredients" *ngFor ="let ingredient of additionalIngredients.controls; let i=index">
        <select [formControlName]="i" class="form-control">
            <option selected value="">Select an ingredient</option>
            <option *ngFor="let ingredient of myfoods" value="{{ ingredient.id }}">{{ ingredient.name }}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

[**DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hobtgg)